SQLITE 3 Can I use variables in "SELECT" query
Can I use variables in a SELECT statement? I am currently using:-
SELECT CAST((JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(ReadingDay)) AS INTEGER) FROM Readings WHERE (JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(ReadingDay)) > 90;

This seems a bit repetitious and complicated to me. Is there some way to simplify this using something like variables so I don't have to calculate the date difference twice?

You can use a derived table (i.e. FROM clause subquery), or cte.

Does this answer your question? Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause

Thank you John that is exactly what I was hoping to do

Try to use a CTE:
WITH DateDiff AS (
SELECT (JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(ReadingDay) as Days
FROM readings)
SELECT CAST(days as int) 
FROM DateDiff 
WHERE days >90;

DateDiff is the name of the CTE, which you call in the main query as it is a table.

Sorry to sound stupid but what is a CTE?
